# SQL Server TRY CATCH IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
BEGIN TRY 
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON 
    INSERT tablename (id,column) VALUES(1,N'value')
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename OFF
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR ('Database already contains data. Skipping insertion.',16,1)
END CATCH
```

throws the error `Incorrect syntax near 'ON'.`

Without the `TRY ... CATCH` block, it works.

I am doing multiple dozen IDENTITY_INSERT ON or OFF, which I wanted to do inside the single `TRY ... CATCH`, do I really have to make multiple dozen `TRY ... CATCH` blocks?

Comment: I wouldn't use TRY/CATCH logic to complete this type of process.  Why don't you use an EXISTS check and if the data doesn't exists, then insert it.

Comment: Are you expecting an `IDENTITY` column to reject an insert if the value already exists?  It doesn't work that way.  An `IDENTITY` column is not a unique constraint--duplicate values are allowed.

Comment: Not if the IDENTITY column is also PRIMARY KEY...

Comment: This syntax works fine for me as long as the `column` text is properly quoted (`[column]`).  Your problem is either in some part of the code not shown here, or else you are at the wrong compatability level.

Comment: @Alexander, an IDENTITY column doesn't have to be a PK. You didn't include the table definition, so I wouldn't know otherwise.

Comment: Is this a one off task or where you planning to do this on a regular basisi? If you have mulitple potential records to put in, use a set based process rather than doing mulitple inserts. Put your data into a staging table and tehn do the insert with a join to that table and a where not exists that refereences the table you are inserting into.  Then it is one step rather than many, it will much faster of a  problem. If you areplanning to do this a stored proc and run from the application, well that means you have a design problem because this sort of thing should not be run from an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st thing 1st, you shouldn't insert values into an identity column, if you do need your influence in values being generated from identity column do not make it an identity column.

Anyway if you do need to do what you are trying to do here, here is some code doing it safely and leaving your table in a healthy state after you have inserted values  explicitly in Identity column.

### add a constraint 1st

```
ALTER TABLE tablename 
ADD CONSTRAINT uu_id UNIQUE (ID)
GO
```

### Code to insert values

```
DECLARE @id INT = 2;
DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(10) = N'Value';



BEGIN TRY 


    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE ID = @id)
      BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Database already contains data. Skipping insertion.',16,1);
      END


   SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON 

     BEGIN TRANSACTION;
       INSERT tablename (id,ColumnName) 
       VALUES( @id , @value)
     COMMIT TRANSACTION; 

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename OFF;

    DBCC CHECKIDENT('tablename', RESEED, 0);
    DBCC CHECKIDENT('tablename', RESEED);  

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

  IF (@@TRANCOUNT <> 0)
   BEGIN
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
   END

       SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()  AS [ERROR_MESSAGE]
             ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS [ERROR_SEVERITY]
             ,ERROR_STATE()    AS [ERROR_STATE]
      -- Do your other error logging here
END CATCH
```

Answer (score -2):

I just found the problem/solution. It's all in the docs, so if someone knows where I can take courses in RTFM, drop me a comment.

As can be read at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175976(v=sql.100).aspx, syntax is

```
BEGIN TRY
     { sql_statement | statement_block }
END TRY
```

so, if you have multiple sql statements, you would write a block, which means

```
BEGIN TRY BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON
    INSERT tablename (id,column) VALUES(1,N'value')
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename OFF
END END TRY
```

Comment: No, that is not the syntax requirement, as can be clearly seen in the later examples from you link.  Nor is there any reason that I know of why that should fix your problem.  It must be something else.